# Paypal Return Input - 404 Not Found

Tags: php, paypal, http-status-code-404

I have a payment system where once the user has finished all the payments they are then redirected back to the site using:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" 
value="newnumyspace.co.uk/purchase-success.php">
```

However this always fails as it is prefixed with

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webapps/newnumyspace.co.uk/purchase-success.php

Is there any way to have the return just newnumyspace.co.uk/purchase-success.php without being changed automatically?

Comment: Could you share more of your code? The given example neither shows a form nor the redirect process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `http` to the beginning of your link.